# Getting error "The operation couldn�t be completed. Operation timed out" with ASIHTTPRequest in iOS

Tags: ios, ios4, nsurlconnection, asihttprequest, connection-timeout

Error is getting thrown immediately after the request call. Any idea how to fix this?

Please find the code and error below:

```
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strUrl]];
            request.shouldAttemptPersistentConnection   = NO;
            [request setShouldContinueWhenAppEntersBackground:YES];
            [request setTimeOutSeconds:600000];
            [request setDelegate:self];
            [request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestFinished:)];
            [request setDidFailSelector:@selector(requestFailed:)];
            [request setDidStartSelector:@selector(requestStarted:)];
            [request startAsynchronous];
```

Error:

> Error Domain=ASIHTTPRequestErrorDomain Code=1 "A connection failure
>   occurred" UserInfo=0x15572bc0 {NSUnderlyingError=0x15570b80 "The
>   operation couldn�t be completed. Operation timed out",
>   NSLocalizedDescription=A connection failure occurred}

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASIHTTPRequestErrorDomain code 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8538449/asihttprequesterrordomain-code-1)

Comment: But the error i am facing is "The operation couldn�t be completed. Operation timed out", where as in the above post is "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -9836.)". Are you sure both are same?

Comment: do you use nszombie or exception breaking point to find where error caught

Comment: It is just calling the delegate of ASIHTTPRequest.                                                        - (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request

Comment: URL is http://devcontent.aviationhub.aero/webnav/resources/C_3475/101781612.0VJC4omyBWB8ibcHntLG3w==.pdf

Comment: @iDev : any clue to fix this?

Comment: It is working fine for most of docs, but failing for only few documents.